# No module named '_tkinter' in DEBIAN

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, raspbian-jessie, modules, tkinter

I have some problems with tkinter.
I want to use it with python 2.7.9 or python 3.4 with DEBIAN but it give me this error in both cases:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Dec  1 2017, 16:25:43) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Can you give me some advice to resolve this?
I already tried

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

but

```
erle@erle-brain:~ $  sudo apt-get install tk-dev
[sudo] password for erle: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tk-dev
```

I also see that maybe I have to install tcl and tk with [this](http://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/piio/wiki?name=Build%20instructions) instructions but:

```
erle@erle-brain:~/build $ sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev libi2c-dev autoconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tcl8.5-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'tcl8.5-dev'
```

Please help me :( I have to finish a University project and I need Tkinter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get Bluetooth/Bluetooth.h for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem doing the `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, then doing `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` and `import tkinter` on the python terminal works. Now I have another issue but I will open a new topic. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In my version of Python 2 the module is called Tkinter (upper case initial T).

In my version of Python 3 the module is called tkinter (lower case initial t).  For Python 3 I had to additionally install tk (`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`).

Comment: I tried to use Python 2.7 but when I write "import Tkinter" in the terminal the error is the same. and also when I try "sudo apt-get install python3-tk"  this is the output: "Package python3-tk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-tk' has no installation candidate "

Comment: The assumption is you are using Raspbian.  Is that correct?  You need to fully specify the environment you are using.

Comment: You're right. I'm using Debian Jessie on raspberryPi3.

Comment: Using Debian rather than Raspbian is outside my experience.