# Where is the CUPS library located in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian-buster, cups

I wanted to install the [driver](https://github.com/codeprofis/dymo-cups-drivers) to my label printer (Dymo LabelWriter 450) on my Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1 device, but the installation breaks with the error `configure: error: Can't find cups library`.

How can I figure out the cups library location? If I would know it, I could pass the link to the installer.

I am using Cups 2.2.10 on Raspbian 10.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of installing [the right package](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi)

Comment: @CoderMike The issue is not about CUPS. The printer requires a driver. CUPS is just a high level framework, but it needs additional device specific information. This is what I would like to install.

Comment: @Dimitry Grigoryev I've never really done cross-compilation and as far as I understand I just have to point the installer to the directory where cups is installed. I would first try with compilation at the raspberry. I know where the binaries are, but that's not enough.

Comment: Have you tried a [**search?**](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=raspberry+pi+printer+drivers&ia=web)

Comment: @Seamus Sure. The installer of the seemingly only driver -- same name, same revision, since it was not updated since 2012 -- for my printer created the error what I have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are multiple sources on the internet which seems to be the same for the Dymo LabelWriter 450 printer driver --- same version code, same file names ---, I was able to install it from [this repo](https://github.com/Kyle-Falconer/DYMO-SDK-for-Linux). I've decided to try it out, because its README mentions a patch implemented in the code. Even though it was not clear that it patched the cups location problem, but it was tested with a relatively recent cups version.

Though it is not an answer to the question, but it is a solution to the problem.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me :)  I'd suggest you select/accept it as **the** answer when you're able (sometimes you have to wait a day or two). It won't stop anyone from submitting another answer, and it won't become a horrible ***zombie question*** that keep coming back.