# Installing Linphone on Raspbian Lite (Buster): Missing directory after compilation

Tags: raspbian-buster

I am attempting to install Linphone (CLI) on RPi 3 Model B (Buster) using this infamous instruction:

https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/#Information

After running

```
make -j4
```

there should be a new directory with all executables:

```
OUTPUT/no-ui/bin
```

Unfortunately, it appears that this directory doesn't get created. I'm getting some errors during the make process, but I can't make much of them.

Due to the character limit, I uploaded my console output here:
https://sharetext.me/untitled-68

Has anyone experienced similar issues and knows what to do?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-mfpu=neon` to your compiler options. The source code includes `arm_neon.h`, which will not compile unless you allow NEON instructions in the compiler output.

Comment: Installing the missing .h headers files would be a help too. OP for every not found you see in there for a file.h. `apt-file search file.h` to find the -dev package containing it, after installing it and updating its database of course.

Comment: @HappyTux Good point. As a side note, Debian has an online [search engine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/119160/33476) for packages and files inside them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compile the program, `linphone` is available on raspbian/Buster:

```
~ $ apt policy linphone

linphone:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.12.0-3
  Version table:
     3.12.0-3 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
```

it can be installed through `apt`:

```
sudo apt install linphone
```