# Running "make" Produces Fatal Error

Tags: c, make

I'm currently trying to get my raspberry pi setup with a VPN. To do so I needed a DNS provider, and so I'm trying to use No-IP's services, and after downloading their files and running a make to start the installation, I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -g -Dlinux -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" noip2.c -o noip2
noip2.c:136:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:25: noip2] Error 1
```

My initial thought is that maybe I don't have the standard c libraries built?

Running Dietpi on a raspberry pi 4.

Comment: `the standard c libraries built` - more like the standard develpper headers not installed - have you "`apt install build-essential`"?

Comment: Check out  [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi) to learn how to search for packages you need to install. In your case it's `libc6-dev`.

Comment: running `apt install build-essential` seemed to take of the issue @Jaromanda X. Also, thank you for pointing me to the package search @Dmitry Grigoryev, very helpful.